# Scala Macros: How to get a Type object of a generic List

Tags: scala, scala-macros, type-parameter

I'm working on a Scala macro where I want to match the type of a `Symbol` to a `List[T]`, where the `T` is a given `Type`. I have the `Type` object of the `T` type parameter already.

It's easy to get the Type object of `List[_]`:

```
  val listType = c.weakTypeOf[List[_]]
```

with this I can already check the typeSignature

```
  sourceParam.typeSignature match {
    case paramType if paramType <:< listType =>
      ....
  }
```

But I want to check paramType with `List[T]`, so how do I make a Type where I take the `List[_]` and some `Type` object and make it a new Type?

Comment: I'm currently not using macro paradise, and I'd rather use the scala-reflect things if I can avoid the macro paradise stuff for now.

Comment: I guess I'm looking for the equivalent of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
scala> val tpeList = typeOf[List[_]]
tpeList: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = scala.List[_]

scala> appliedType(tpeList, List(typeOf[Int]))
res0: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = scala.List[Int]
```

Comment: That works! The docs for appliedType are here: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/scala/reflect/api/Types.html